# Jumping forward with the continuation monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, continuations, monad-transformers

It is possible to jump backward in a program with the continuation monad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}

import Control.Monad.Fix
import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont

setjmp = callCC (\c -> return (fix c))

backward = do
  l <- setjmp
  -- some code to be repeated forever
  l
```

But when I try to jump forward, it is not accepted by GHC:

```
forward = mdo
  l
  -- some dead code
  l <- setjmp  
  return ()
```

This does not work because there is no instance for `MonadFix (ContT r m)` for the continuation monad transformer `ContT` defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Cont`. See Section 5.1 of [Levent Erkok's thesis](http://digitalcommons.ohsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1163&context=etd) for further details.

Is there a way to encode forward jump without value recursion for the continuation monad?

Is there an alternative definition of `ContT` that has an instance for `MonadFix (ContT r m)`? There is an [unpublished draft](http://www.carlssonia.org/ogi/mdo-callcc.pdf) by Magnus Carlsson that makes such proposal but I am not sure what to do of it in my case.

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to do much better than @bennofs's suggestion (although you could probably define some helping functions to make it less awkward.) For example, what should `mdo l; x <- lift $ getChar; l <- setjmp; print x` do, and how would you implement it?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Good point! (1) What it should do: execution should be suspended until the value of `x` is ready for `print` (in your example, it is never ready so it is suspended forever). (2) How do I implement it: This should be automatic by laziness.

Comment: Is there a somewhat more complete example of what you're trying to accomplish?  You can jump back with arguments, maybe that's sufficient for your task?

Comment: @JohnL: I just want to understand continuations. I read that continuations are enough to implement goto in a functional language. But I cannot see how to jump forward in Haskell. Please write an answer about "jumping with arguments".

Comment: Maybe you are asking about `Monad Goto`.
Try this :
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GotoT-transformers-1.0.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Goto.html

Comment: @viorior: How does it work?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it if you move your dead code inside the `callCC`, like this:

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

forward :: ContT () IO ()
forward = do
  callCC $ \skip -> do
    skip ()
    lift $ putStrLn "This is not executed"
  lift $ putStrLn "Control flow continues here"

main :: IO ()
main = runContT forward return
```

It's not possible to do exactly what you want. To see why, consider this example:

```
mdo
  l
  c <- lift getChar
  l <- if c == 'a' then setjmp else return (return ())
  lift $ putStrLn "end"
```

What should this do?

---

You can also jump back later to the code that was skipped. You just need to pass a continuation to the code you skipped. Using your example, `goto L2: L1: some code; goto END; L2: goto L1; END: return` can be implemented as:

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

forward :: ContT () IO ()
forward = do
  callCC $ \end -> do
    l1 <- callCC $ \l2 -> do
      callCC $ \l1 -> l2 l1
      liftIO $ putStrLn "In L1"
      end ()
    liftIO $ putStrLn "In L2"
    l1 ()
  liftIO $ putStrLn "End"

main :: IO ()
main = runContT forward return
```

Here we pass the continuation to the part we skipped (`l1`) back to the outer code so that it can jump there.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer, but the point here is not to have dead code (easy enough), but it is to be able to jump forward in some code.

Comment: How does this not jump forward? It jumps to `lift $ putStrLn "This is not executed"`, which is further in the code?

Comment: @Bob updated the <strike>question</strike> answer to include an example why it's impossible

Comment: With your answer, there is no way to jump back later in the code that was skipped. So it is really dead code. I would like something like `goto L2: L1: some code; goto END; L2: goto L1; END: return ()`

Comment: Can you equip your answer with helping functions such as `setjmp` to make forward jump look less awkward, and possibly as cute as backward jump?